# CakePHP 3 use beforeRender in AppController of Plugin?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How do I go about having the beforeRender method fire in the AppController of a CakePHP 3.x Plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override `beforeRender` in controller. If will fire automaticly when given controller will be used for current URL to handle the request
.